# Can I get Laravel's passport login method to check a validated field in my users table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel project using passport to authenticate login attempts via the /outh/token route. I need this method to also check if a field called 'validated' in the users table is set to true. If it's not don't let them login and present a message that says something to the effect of "Your account is not activated, please check the email we have sent you to activate your account".

Would the only way to do this be to create a custom login controller? And how safe is it to do that in terms of, is there anything extra passport does apart from checking the username and password and generating a password grant token?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use a custom middleware instead of modifying the oauth routes. You could simply query the user record to check if they are activated and redirect away if not.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (!auth()->user()->activated) { 
        return redirect('home');
    } 
    return $next($request);
}
```